# How do I change the default application for unknown file types?

Tags: nautilus, gedit

Ever since installing Bless Hex Editor, all unknown files and text files automatically open with Bless instead of gedit. How do I change it back? I don't want to have to manually associate files with gedit, I just want gedit to be the default if there's no other application set up to open the file.

**Solution:**
modify `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
[Default Applications] 
- text/plain=bless.desktop
- application/octet-stream=bless.desktop
+ application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: [mimeapps.list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/710556/)  

defaults.list was just replaced with the distro default after upgrading to 11.10.  
I can see the bless entries entries there. Can I just delete them to revert back to the system default?

Comment: to answer my own question, yes, deleting the offending lines from mineppas.list fixes things. Firefox is still wanting to open stuff with bless though...

Comment: That's odd, Firefox seems to use the system settings on my computer. Did you try restarting the computer (or restarting Firefox) after deleting the bless entries in mimeapps.list?

Comment: Ah, fixed it. The problem was that there is no default for application/octet-stream, so it was using bliss as it existed under "Added Association". So to fix, instead of removing the line in Default Applications:  
application/octet-stream=bliss.desktop  
I changed it to:  
application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop

Comment: @dmuir If you have solved your own question, it'd be great if you posted it as an answer and accepted it so we know it's been taken care of. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

modify `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
[Default Applications] 
- text/plain=bless.desktop
- application/octet-stream=bless.desktop
+ application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop
```

This reverts the text/plain app to using the system default in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, and changes the default `application/octet-stream`. It seems that Firefox labels this mime-type as "Unknown".

Comment: Is it only possible to set these defaults with a `.desktop` file and not a general path to the selected program ?

Answer (score 2):

right click on the unknown file, properties, open with. If your desired application is in the list, click on it, if not then click on the Show Other Applications and select the one you want.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On **Fedora using KDE**, I went to:

> System Settings -> Applications -> File Associations -> search for "plain"

"Text - Plain", then set your preferred program. This worked for me.